# SUM UP THE BALANCE OF EACH MARKET

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi Everyone I'm running into the problem of summing the total saleytd for my case statement.  I've tried putting a sum function in front of the SalesYTD and the error I get is synthax errors next to sales. I've also tried grouping by salesytd and that doesn't work because it gives me this error Column 'PERSON.STATEPROVINCE.StateProvinceID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause. Here my query below. My query works fine i just get it to sum my totals.

```
 USE AdventureWorks2014; 

 GO 

 SELECT  STATEPROVINCEID,A.NAME,A.COUNTRYREGIONCODE,(b.SALESYTD),  

 CASE 

 WHEN A.TerritoryID = '1' THEN 'WESTERN MARKET' 

 WHEN A.TerritoryID = '2' THEN 'NORTH EASTERN MARKET'

WHEN A.TerritoryID =  '3' THEN 'MID WESTERN MARKET' 

WHEN A.TerritoryID =  '4' THEN 'SOUTH WESTERN MARKET' 

WHEN A.TerritoryID =  '5' THEN 'SOUTH EASTERN MARKET' 
 ELSE 'OTHER' 

 END AS MARKET


FROM PERSON.STATEPROVINCE as A INNER JOIN SALES.SalesTerritory AS B

ON A.TerritoryID = B.TerritoryID 

WHERE A.CountryRegionCode = 'US'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the total sales year to date for the South Western market, then you can do a conditional aggregation over the `SALESYTD` column for that market:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN A.TerritoryID = '4' THEN b.SALESYTD ELSE 0 END) AS total_sales
FROM PERSON.STATEPROVINCE a
INNER JOIN SALES.SalesTerritory b
    ON a.TerritoryID = b.TerritoryID
WHERE a.CountryRegionCode = 'US'
```

If you want sums for *all* territories, then you can use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT a.TerritoryID, SUM(b.SALESYTD) AS total_sales
FROM PERSON.STATEPROVINCE a
INNER JOIN SALES.SalesTerritory b
    ON a.TerritoryID = b.TerritoryID
WHERE a.CountryRegionCode = 'US'
GROUP BY a.TerritoryID
```

Comment: How about all sales from all markets and a column for the markets?  like south west = $700 million

Answer (score 0):

I finally got everything to work. thanks everyone. here my query

```
SELECT SUM(b.SALESYTD) AS TOTALSALES,

case

when a.TerritoryID = '1' then 'WESTERN MARKET' 

WHEN A.TERRITORYID = '2' THEN 'NORTH EASTERN MARKET' 

when a.TerritoryID = '3' then 'MID WESTERN MARKET' 

WHEN A.TerritoryID = '4' THEN 'SOUTH WESTERN MARKET' 

WHEN A.TERRITORYID = '5' THEN 'SOUTH EASTERN MARKET' 

else 'OTHER' 

end as MARKETS

FROM PERSON.STATEPROVINCE a

INNER JOIN SALES.SalesTerritory b

ON a.TerritoryID = b.TerritoryID

WHERE a.CountryRegionCode = 'US'

GROUP BY a.TerritoryID
```